# LINQ query return

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm using highcharts to show some data...however i'm having issues due to my query not returning the data in the correct format for some charts.

Year   Key     Value
2011   Key1    5
2011   Key2    10
2012   Key1    12
2012   Key2    8
2013   Key1    3

Here's part of my query:

```
XAxisList = db.Datas.Where(w => w.CategoryID == measurementID).Select(x => x.Year).Distinct(),
Data = from d in db.Datas
       where d.CategoryID == measurementID
       group d by d.DataKey into g
       select new
                 {
                   Key = g.Key,
                   Values = g.Select(s => s.Value)
                 }
```

Here is what my linq query returns:

```
"XAxisList": [
  "2011",
  "2012",
  "2013"
],
"Data": [
  {
    "Key": "Key1",
    "Values": [
      "5",
      "12"
      "3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "Key2",
    "Values": [
      "10",
      "8"
    ]
  }      
]
```

**How would I add a 'null' array value in the Key2 values so it would look like below?**

```
"XAxisList": [
  "2011",
  "2012",
  "2013"
],
"Data": [
  {
    "Key": "Key1",
    "Values": [
      "5",
      "12"
      "3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "Key2",
    "Values": [
      "10",
      "8",
      **null**
    ]
  }      
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?  Make sure that the `Values` array always has 3 entries?

Comment: Yes pretty much, but not necessarily fixed to 3. A user may add one for example to 2011 but not 2012 because there's no data for 2012. So, when I go to build my chart it messes up my series data. I'm fairly new to linq...didn't know if there was a way to do it. I can always restructure my data and parse it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply cannot be done, based on your dataset. If your dataset contained the following record

2013 Key2 null

then there wouldn't have been any issue.

You could understand, why this cannot be done, if you think about the following:

```
group d by d.DataKey into g
```

What are you doing there?

You are grouping your records based of the `DataKey` property. Since there are two different keys, `key1` and `key2`, there would be two groups. The group of `key1` would have three records and the group of `key2` would have two records.

Furthermore, I don't see any way that you could overcome this. As I can understand by your data, you have some yearly values for some keys and you want to use them for creating a chart.

Now there is missing a value for the `key2` and the year `2013`. So you think that if you could add a `null` at the end of the corresponding sequence everything would be ok.

```
{
    "Key": "Key2",
    "Values": [
        "10",
        "8",
        "null"
    ]
}
```

Have you thinked about what would be the situation of missing a value for 2012? It would be exactly the same ! So adding a null at the end of the `Values` array wouldn't make any sense.

If the `Year` values would be specific or in a specific range I could come up with an idea, but I am not sure that this is the case.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm fairly new to linq...wasn't sure if there was a way to do it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the modification for reporting or charts after the query, or it'll get extremely messy:

```
XAxisList = db.Datas.Where(w => w.CategoryID == measurementID).Select(x => x.Year).Distinct(),
Data = //your query

int largest = Data.Values.Max(v => v.Count);
foreach(var d in Data)
{
    while(d.Values.Count < largest)
         d.Values.Add(null);
}
```

Or similar.  You'll probably need to make your `Values` a list with `ToList` to get the `Add` method.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I may give this a try, but thought about organizing my query data a little differently